# proguard keeping enumerated type names in class file

Tags: java, ant, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate an enumerated type file in java and I've noticed that I can get proguard to obfuscate the names of the enumerated types like I want, including the references, however it keeps the old names of the enumerated types in the class file.

For example:

Proguard Configuration:

```
<project name="Library" default="obfuscate" basedir=".">

<taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties" classpath="proguard.jar"/>

<target name="build">
  <javac srcdir="src" includeantruntime="true" destdir="build">
    <compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation" />
  </javac>

  <jar jarfile="jarfile.jar" basedir="build" />

</target>

<target name="obfuscate">
  <taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties"
           classpath="lib/proguard.jar" />

  <proguard printmapping="out.map"
            allowaccessmodification="true"
            obfuscationdictionary="random.txt"
            classobfuscationdictionary="random-c.txt"
            packageobfuscationdictionary="random-p.txt"
            renamesourcefileattribute="SourceFile">

    <!-- Specify the input jars, output jars, and library jars. -->

    <injar  file="jarfile.jar" />
    <outjar file="output/library_out.jar" />

    <libraryjar file="${java.home}/lib/rt.jar" />

    <!-- Keep some useful attributes. -->

    <keepattribute name="InnerClasses" />
    <keepattribute name="SourceFile" />
    <keepattribute name="LineNumberTable" />
    <keepattribute name="Deprecated" />
    <keepattribute name="*Annotation*" />

    <keep name="test.**" allowobfuscation="true">
        <field access="public protected" />
        <method access="public protected" />
    </keep>
    <keepclassmembernames access="public">
        <method access = "public static"
                type   = "void"
                name   = "main"
                parameters = "java.lang.String[]"/>
    </keepclassmembernames>
    <keepclassmembernames access="public">
      <method type      ="java.lang.Class"
              name      ="class$"
              parameters="java.lang.String" />
      <method type      ="java.lang.Class"
              name      ="class$"
              parameters="java.lang.String,boolean" />
    </keepclassmembernames>

    <!-- Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes. -->

    <keepclasseswithmembernames includedescriptorclasses="true">
      <method access="native" />
    </keepclasseswithmembernames>

    <!-- Preserve the methods that are required in all enumeration classes. -->

    <keepclassmembers allowoptimization="true" type="enum">
      <method access="public static"
              type="**[]"
              name="values"
              parameters="" />
      <method access="public static"
              type="**"
              name="valueOf"
              parameters="java.lang.String" />
    </keepclassmembers>

    <!-- Explicitly preserve all serialization members. The Serializable
         interface is only a marker interface, so it wouldn't save them.
         You can comment this out if your library doesn't use serialization.
         If your code contains serializable classes that have to be backward
         compatible, please refer to the manual. -->

    <keepclassmembers implements="java.io.Serializable">
      <field  access    ="final"
              type      ="long"
              name      ="serialVersionUID" />
      <field  access    ="static final"
              type      ="java.io.ObjectStreamField[]"
              name      ="serialPersistentFields" />
      <method access    ="private"
              type      ="void"
              name      ="writeObject"
              parameters="java.io.ObjectOutputStream" />
      <method access    ="private"
              type      ="void"
              name      ="readObject"
              parameters="java.io.ObjectInputStream" />
      <method type      ="java.lang.Object"
              name      ="writeReplace"
              parameters="" />
      <method type      ="java.lang.Object"
              name      ="readResolve"
              parameters="" />
    </keepclassmembers>

    <!-- Your application may contain more items that need to be preserved;
      typically classes that are dynamically created using Class.forName -->

  </proguard>
</target>

</project>
```

Two Java Files:

mainClass.java:

```
package test;

public class mainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(TestEnum.TEST);
    System.out.println(TestEnum.TESTAGAIN);
    System.out.println(TestEnum.TESTAGAINAGAIN);
  }
}
```

TestEnum.java:

```
package test;
public enum TestEnum {
  TEST,
  TESTAGAIN,
  TESTAGAINAGAIN;
}
```

"obfuscated" class file of TestEnum.java contains the following Strings:

```
> $ strings ff42d24eb40678f60462c47c07218c6ba0be/fdbdd99cf9e2f8336f5ac70ee1c6b0c002e23d44.class

()Ljava/lang/Object;
R()[Lff42d24eb40678f60462c47c07218c6ba0be/fdbdd99cf9e2f8336f5ac70ee1c6b0c002e23d44;
5(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum;
c(Ljava/lang/String;)Lff42d24eb40678f60462c47c07218c6ba0be/fdbdd99cf9e2f8336f5ac70ee1c6b0c002e23d44;
(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
<clinit>
<init>
Code
OLff42d24eb40678f60462c47c07218c6ba0be/fdbdd99cf9e2f8336f5ac70ee1c6b0c002e23d44;
TEST
    TESTAGAIN
TESTAGAINAGAIN
P[Lff42d24eb40678f60462c47c07218c6ba0be/fdbdd99cf9e2f8336f5ac70ee1c6b0c002e23d44;
(bd5e3e98f5d9552fad4cea7dd9f09ec970b5c537
c4b09ad3a6fc8bdb613d7a47ae6b62
clone
$f0330a7bb6fff9a6c846ffe92c696633cc9c
'fca7ea2fd7d090d4fc3b0f2f22c2a234b16cebb
Mff42d24eb40678f60462c47c07218c6ba0be/fdbdd99cf9e2f8336f5ac70ee1c6b0c002e23d44
java/lang/Enum
valueOf
values@1
```

Here is the string dump of the mainClass:

```
> $ strings ff42d24eb40678f60462c47c07218c6ba0be/e254fec352c913191237dc8c2e9030b20da756f2.class 

(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
([Ljava/lang/String;)V
<init>
Code
OLff42d24eb40678f60462c47c07218c6ba0be/fdbdd99cf9e2f8336f5ac70ee1c6b0c002e23d44;
Ljava/io/PrintStream;
(bd5e3e98f5d9552fad4cea7dd9f09ec970b5c537
$f0330a7bb6fff9a6c846ffe92c696633cc9c
'fca7ea2fd7d090d4fc3b0f2f22c2a234b16cebb
Mff42d24eb40678f60462c47c07218c6ba0be/e254fec352c913191237dc8c2e9030b20da756f2
Mff42d24eb40678f60462c47c07218c6ba0be/fdbdd99cf9e2f8336f5ac70ee1c6b0c002e23d44
java/io/PrintStream
java/lang/Object
java/lang/System
main
println
```

As you can see TEST, TESTAGAIN, and TESTAGAINAGAIN are still contained within the class file but are not actually used in mainClass, instead their obfuscated name is used.

In fact, if you look at these class files in a program like JD-GUI, they don't show up either, but they are contained within the class file themselves.  Is there some way to remove the TEST, TESTAGAIN, and TESTAGAINAGAIN within the class file via proguard?

This was run with proguard 5.3.3, compiling with java 8.  An example of this can be found here: https://github.com/mirabellatook/ant-proguard-example

Comment: It might be, cause enumerated items can be referenced by name, like `Enum.valueOf(TestEnum.class, "TEST")`... Thus if you change the name, the name looses its value...

Comment: That seems likely.  In fact I found the following feature request: https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/feature-requests/141/  What I wonder is if proguard has some way to know that I'm not referencing via valueOf and remove those constants somehow?